Upgrading a Winform application that used ASP.NET Identity
Here is my scenario: I have a winforms app targeting .NET 4.7 that I would like to update as its getting more and more difficult to maintain.  One of its functions (among many) is to orchestrate user permissions for several mvc application that use asp.net identity.
To do this I have a class library that references asp.net identity and performs all the management tasks necessary to maintain the identity database on the website.
I want to update the winforms application to .NET 8.0 (or even 9 if it lets me).  I cannot update the class library to .NET core as it requires me to update the identity to identity-core which uses EFcore and a different schema from asp.net identity.  I don't want to do this as it will break all my MVC applications which I don't have time to rewrite now.
My question is how can I still use this class library from a .NET 8 winforms application?
Is there any wrapper that will allow me to keep the asp.net identity within a .NET core library?  Any suggestions are welcome

My backup plan is to write my own management library for asp.net identity in .NET 8.  Preferably I would like to save some work.
